# Get fields of a widget

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, metabox

I have a widget that has fields, so how can I get these fields in my Metabox.

I have tried with this variable `$wp_registered_widgets`, but I can't get the fields.

Is there any solution for my problem and thanks.

[Update]

here is the code of metabox

```
<?php



add_action('add_meta_boxes','dar_meta_create');

function dar_meta_create()
{
    add_meta_box(  
        'dar_meta', // $id  
        'metabox dardar', // $title   
        'dar_meta_function', // $callback  
        'page', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high');
}

// callback

function dar_meta_function($post)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'dar_nonce');


    // my form

    $nbr1 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'nombre1',true);
    $nbr2 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'nombre2',true);

    echo 
    '<input type="text" value="'.wp_kses_post($nbr1).'" id="nombre1" name="nombre1"> 
    <input type="text" value="'.wp_kses_post($nbr2).'" id="nombre2" name="nombre2">';

     //******************************************************//

         //  I want get and display fields of a specific widget 


       //*****************************************************//


}

// save meta box

function dar_meta_save($id,$post)
{

// check the autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $id; 

    if (
        'page' == $post->post_type
        && current_user_can('edit_page', $id)
        && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dar_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))
        && isset($_POST['nombre1']) && isset($_POST['nombre2'])
    ) 
    {
    update_post_meta($id, 'nombre1', strip_tags($_POST['nombre1']));
    update_post_meta($id, 'nombre2', strip_tags($_POST['nombre2']));
    }

}
add_action('save_post','dar_meta_save',1,2);
```

Comment: Can you also add the code you have been working  on? It will help :)

Comment: @MarutiMohanty I update my question :)

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. Can you please explain a little more on what you want to do here.. if possible do it with examples.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty :

Description of plugin that I want to create : 

I'm trying the create a plugin like homepage builder :

list all widgets in a metabox, when a user click in a widget a models apear for display the fields of this widget.

So my problem how can I list all the widgets with their fiels ?

Comment: @FÔxGênki I can't understand if you want ot retrive the widget saved settings for a widget instance or just the field names of a widget

Comment: @G.M. I want retrive all informations about a field of a widget for example ( name, class, id , type of the field...)

Comment: @FÔxGênki This informations are not saved anywhere, they stay just in code, so you have to write code in a way that make them accessible, e.g. putting these fields in static variables of the widget class. Also consider that real id and name (the ones used as id an name attributes in the widget form inputs) are unique per instance, (if you correctly set them using `get_field_name` and `get_field_id` methods).